# Track the page view in one single html using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am doing website in html5. Here I used all pages in "one html" and page view controlling by jQuery. In my html each page has a separate "ID". I need to track individual page using google analytics. If there is any way to find the solution, please provide me answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, then have a look at the [pagechange event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/).

You could do this:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', function (event, ui) {
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/pagename/']);
}
```